# Functionbeat gets deployed as lambda, but the status shows no data received for cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch, functionbeat

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-installation-configuration.html) and configured and deployed functionbeat for a cloudwatch log group. I also added the elastic search and the kibana endpoints. Here are the outputs

```
MacBook-Pro:functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64 user$ ./functionbeat setup -e
2021-10-20T22:57:35.097-0400    INFO    instance/beat.go:645    Home path: [/Users/user/functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64] Config path: [/Users/user/functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64] Data path: [/tmp] Logs path: [/tmp/logs]
2021-10-20T22:57:35.098-0400    INFO    instance/beat.go:653    Beat ID: c9cbbe8c-319a-4577-be8e-de223fba4f6e
2021-10-20T22:57:35.100-0400    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:981    Beat info   {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/Users/user/functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64", "data": "/tmp", "home": "/Users/user/functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64", "logs": "/tmp/logs"}, "type": "functionbeat", "uuid": "c9cbbe8c-319a-4577-be8e-de223fba4f6e"}}}
2021-10-20T22:57:35.100-0400    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:990    Build info  {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "aacf9ecd9c494aa0908f61fbca82c906b16562a8", "libbeat": "7.10.2", "time": "2021-01-12T22:39:38.000Z", "version": "7.10.2"}}}
2021-10-20T22:57:35.100-0400    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:993    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"darwin","arch":"amd64","max_procs":8,"version":"go1.14.12"}}}
2021-10-20T22:57:35.101-0400    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:997    Host info   {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2021-10-13T02:09:16.051008-04:00","name":"Jijos-MacBook-Pro.local","ip":["127.0.0.1/8","::1/128","fe80::1/64","fe80::1ce5:e86b:6d5c:88d9/64","192.168.1.11/24","fe80::84d7:afff:fe5e:107c/64","fe80::84d7:afff:fe5e:107c/64","fe80::46cf:bba0:8bb3:5b62/64","fe80::99c:e0d2:dbd5:e7aa/64","fe80::cdce:ea46:e3c:3feb/64","fe80::76aa:a49d:6061:d997/64","fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122/64"],"kernel_version":"20.6.0","mac":["a6:83:e7:8a:24:01","a4:83:e7:8a:24:01","86:d7:af:5e:10:7c","86:d7:af:5e:10:7c","82:ea:c5:62:c4:05","82:ea:c5:62:c4:04","82:ea:c5:62:c4:01","82:ea:c5:62:c4:00","82:ea:c5:62:c4:01","ac:de:48:00:11:22"],"os":{"family":"darwin","platform":"darwin","name":"Mac OS X","version":"10.16","major":10,"minor":16,"patch":0,"build":"20G165"},"timezone":"EDT","timezone_offset_sec":-14400,"id":"BEEB9A65-6CAE-51E9-B16E-BCE2FBB9EED9"}}}
2021-10-20T22:57:35.101-0400    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1026   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"cwd": "/Users/user/functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64", "exe": "./functionbeat", "name": "functionbeat", "pid": 13218, "ppid": 8720, "start_time": "2021-10-20T22:57:34.835-0400"}}}
2021-10-20T22:57:35.101-0400    INFO    instance/beat.go:299    Setup Beat: functionbeat; Version: 7.10.2
2021-10-20T22:57:35.102-0400    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:184  Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'functionbeat-7.10.2' as ILM is enabled.
2021-10-20T22:57:35.103-0400    INFO    eslegclient/connection.go:99    elasticsearch url: https://l-es.xyz.io:443
2021-10-20T22:57:35.106-0400    INFO    [publisher] pipeline/module.go:113  Beat name: Jijos-MacBook-Pro.local
2021-10-20T22:57:35.107-0400    INFO    eslegclient/connection.go:99    elasticsearch url: https://l-es.xyz.io:443
2021-10-20T22:57:35.316-0400    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:314   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.10.2
2021-10-20T22:57:35.366-0400    INFO    template/load.go:183    Existing template will be overwritten, as overwrite is enabled.
2021-10-20T22:57:35.420-0400    INFO    template/load.go:117    Try loading template functionbeat-7.10.2 to Elasticsearch
2021-10-20T22:57:35.496-0400    INFO    template/load.go:109    template with name 'functionbeat-7.10.2' loaded.
2021-10-20T22:57:35.496-0400    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:298  Loaded index template.
Index setup finished.
```

On deploying the functionbeat, I was able to successfully deploy it as well

```
MacBook-Pro:functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64 user$ ./functionbeat -v -e -d "*" deploy fn-cloudwatch-logs
2021-10-20T22:58:30.531-0400    INFO    instance/beat.go:645    Home path: [/Users/user/functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64] Config path: [/Users/user/functionbeat-7.10.2-darwin-x86_64] Data path: [/tmp] Logs path: [/tmp/logs]
2021-10-20T22:58:30.532-0400    DEBUG   [beat]  instance/beat.go:697    Beat metadata path: /tmp/meta.json
2021-10-20T22:58:30.532-0400    INFO    instance/beat.go:653    Beat ID: c9cbbe8c-319a-4577-be8e-de223fba4f6e
2021-10-20T22:58:30.535-0400    DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:126 add_cloud_metadata: starting to fetch metadata, timeout=3s
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:162 add_cloud_metadata: received disposition for azure after 3.000470363s. result=[provider:azure, error=failed requesting azure metadata: Get "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute?api-version=2017-04-02": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout, metadata={}]
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:162 add_cloud_metadata: received disposition for aws after 3.000674614s. result=[provider:aws, error=failed requesting aws metadata: Get "http://169.254.169.254/2014-02-25/dynamic/instance-identity/document": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout, metadata={}]
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:162 add_cloud_metadata: received disposition for openstack after 3.000710413s. result=[provider:openstack, error=failed requesting openstack metadata: Get "http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout, metadata={}]
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:162 add_cloud_metadata: received disposition for gcp after 3.000737886s. result=[provider:gcp, error=failed requesting gcp metadata: Get "http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/?recursive=true&alt=json": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout, metadata={}]
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:162 add_cloud_metadata: received disposition for digitalocean after 3.000758996s. result=[provider:digitalocean, error=failed requesting digitalocean metadata: Get "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1.json": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: i/o timeout, metadata={}]
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:129 add_cloud_metadata: fetchMetadata ran for 3.000778492s
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    INFO    [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go:89 add_cloud_metadata: hosting provider type not detected.
2021-10-20T22:58:33.536-0400    DEBUG   [processors]    processors/processor.go:120 Generated new processors: add_host_metadata=[netinfo.enabled=[true], cache.ttl=[5m0s]], add_cloud_metadata={}
2021-10-20T22:58:33.538-0400    DEBUG   [cli-handler]   cmd/cli_handler.go:52   Starting deploy for: fn-cloudwatch-logs
2021-10-20T22:58:33.539-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/cli_manager.go:119  Deploying function: fn-cloudwatch-logs
2021-10-20T22:58:33.539-0400    DEBUG   [provider]  aws/template_builder.go:90  Compressing all assets into an artifact
2021-10-20T22:58:35.284-0400    DEBUG   [provider]  aws/template_builder.go:96  Compression is successful (zip size: 22046351 bytes)
2021-10-20T22:58:35.339-0400    INFO    [provider]  aws/template_builder.go:155 No role is configured for function fn-cloudwatch-logs, creating a custom role.
2021-10-20T22:58:35.342-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/cli_manager.go:69   Using cloudformation template:
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "fnbfncloudwatchlogs": {
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": "functionbeat-deploy-bucket-test-poc",
          "S3Key": "functionbeat-deployment/fn-cloudwatch-logs/eMPnb_aKewcOO0XW-fgVUvvN0PXWxEDkvxFexJEI-zY/functionbeat.zip"
        },
        "Description": "lambda function for cloudwatch logs",
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "BEAT_STRICT_PERMS": "false",
            "ENABLED_FUNCTIONS": "fn-cloudwatch-logs"
          }
        },
        "FunctionName": "fn-cloudwatch-logs",
        "Handler": "functionbeat-aws",
        "MemorySize": 128,
        "ReservedConcurrentExecutions": 5,
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "fnbfncloudwatchlogsIAMRoleLambdaExecution",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Runtime": "go1.x",
        "Timeout": 3
      },
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    },
    "fnbfncloudwatchlogsIAMRoleLambdaExecution": {
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "lambda.",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::URLSuffix"
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                  ],
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Resource": [
                    {
                      "Fn::Sub": "arn:${AWS::Partition}:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/fn-cloudwatch-logs:*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "PolicyName": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  "fnb",
                  "lambda",
                  "fn-cloudwatch-logs"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "RoleName": "functionbeat-lambda-fn-cloudwatch-logs"
      },
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role"
    },
    "fnbfncloudwatchlogsLogGroup": {
      "Properties": {
        "LogGroupName": "/aws/lambda/fn-cloudwatch-logs"
      },
      "Type": "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    },
    "fnbfncloudwatchlogsPermission0": {
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "fnbfncloudwatchlogs",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Principal": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "logs.",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              ".",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::URLSuffix"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "SourceArn": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "arn:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
              },
              ":logs:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
              },
              ":log-group:",
              "/aws/containerinsights/translator-eks-ci-blue-cluster/application",
              ":*"
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    },
    "fnbfncloudwatchlogsSFawscontainerinsightstranslatoreksciblueclusterapplication": {
      "Properties": {
        "DestinationArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "fnbfncloudwatchlogs",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "FilterPattern": "mylog_",
        "LogGroupName": "/aws/containerinsights/translator-eks-ci-blue-cluster/application"
      },
      "Type": "AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter"
    }
  }
}
2021-10-20T22:58:35.343-0400    DEBUG   [aws.executor]  executor/executor.go:53 The executor is executing '6' operations for converging state
2021-10-20T22:58:35.343-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_ensure_bucket.go:33  Verifying presence of S3 bucket: functionbeat-deploy-bucket-test-poc
2021-10-20T22:58:35.548-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_upload_to_bucket.go:44   Uploading file 'functionbeat-deployment/fn-cloudwatch-logs/eMPnb_aKewcOO0XW-fgVUvvN0PXWxEDkvxFexJEI-zY/functionbeat.zip' to bucket 'functionbeat-deploy-bucket-test-poc' with size 22046351 bytes
2021-10-20T22:58:36.286-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_upload_to_bucket.go:57   Upload successful
2021-10-20T22:58:36.287-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_upload_to_bucket.go:44   Uploading file 'functionbeat-deployment/fn-cloudwatch-logs/2_AZvlkBMEoQfFeV_dSW5B2VD927AWycnifwEPnFtcI/cloudformation-template-create.json' to bucket 'functionbeat-deploy-bucket-test-poc' with size 4231 bytes
2021-10-20T22:58:36.328-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_upload_to_bucket.go:57   Upload successful
2021-10-20T22:58:36.328-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:48 Creating CloudFormation create stack request
2021-10-20T22:58:36.848-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack, LogicalResourceId: fnb-fn-cloudwatch-logs-stack, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, ResourceStatusReason: User Initiated
2021-10-20T22:58:40.973-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::IAM::Role, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsIAMRoleLambdaExecution, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
2021-10-20T22:58:40.973-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Logs::LogGroup, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsLogGroup, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
2021-10-20T22:58:43.035-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::IAM::Role, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsIAMRoleLambdaExecution, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, ResourceStatusReason: Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-20T22:58:43.035-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Logs::LogGroup, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsLogGroup, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, ResourceStatusReason: Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-20T22:58:45.091-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Logs::LogGroup, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsLogGroup, ResourceStatus: CREATE_COMPLETE
2021-10-20T22:58:55.375-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::IAM::Role, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsIAMRoleLambdaExecution, ResourceStatus: CREATE_COMPLETE
2021-10-20T22:58:57.429-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Lambda::Function, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogs, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
2021-10-20T22:59:01.542-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Lambda::Function, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogs, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, ResourceStatusReason: Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-20T22:59:05.670-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Lambda::Function, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogs, ResourceStatus: CREATE_COMPLETE
2021-10-20T22:59:07.727-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Lambda::Permission, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsPermission0, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
2021-10-20T22:59:07.728-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsSFawscontainerinsightstranslatoreksciblueclusterapplication, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
2021-10-20T22:59:07.728-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Lambda::Permission, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsPermission0, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, ResourceStatusReason: Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-20T22:59:07.728-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsSFawscontainerinsightstranslatoreksciblueclusterapplication, ResourceStatus: CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, ResourceStatusReason: Resource creation Initiated
2021-10-20T22:59:07.728-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsSFawscontainerinsightstranslatoreksciblueclusterapplication, ResourceStatus: CREATE_COMPLETE
2021-10-20T22:59:18.052-0400    INFO    [aws]   aws/op_cloudformation.go:97 Stack event received, ResourceType: AWS::Lambda::Permission, LogicalResourceId: fnbfncloudwatchlogsPermission0, ResourceStatus: CREATE_COMPLETE
2021-10-20T22:59:19.735-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_delete_file_bucket.go:38 Removing file 'functionbeat-deployment/fn-cloudwatch-logs/eMPnb_aKewcOO0XW-fgVUvvN0PXWxEDkvxFexJEI-zY/functionbeat.zip' on bucket 'functionbeat-deploy-bucket-test-poc'
2021-10-20T22:59:19.808-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/op_delete_file_bucket.go:51 Remove successful
2021-10-20T22:59:19.808-0400    DEBUG   [aws.executor]  executor/executor.go:68 All operations successful
2021-10-20T22:59:19.808-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/cli_manager.go:125  Successfully created function 'fn-cloudwatch-logs'
2021-10-20T22:59:19.808-0400    DEBUG   [aws]   aws/cli_manager.go:126  Deploy finish for function 'fn-cloudwatch-logs'
Function: fn-cloudwatch-logs, deploy successful
2021-10-20T22:59:19.810-0400    DEBUG   [cli-handler]   cmd/cli_handler.go:64   Deploy execution ended
```

In the aws console I see that the function `fn-cloudwatch-logs` is being created and I also see the cloudformation template in the s3 bucket. I also see that a trigger is being added to the cloudwatch log group, but the functionbeat status in kibana says that `No Data is being received`.

[image: functionbeat status]

I also tried giving a sample log data to the lambda function and it ends up throwing a `Could not parse events from cloudwatch` error in the cloudwatch

```
2021-10-21T19:17:32.605Z    ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://******.io:443)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: 169.254.40.221 requires the default distribution of Elasticsearch. Please update to the default distribution of Elasticsearch for full access to all free features, or switch to the OSS distribution of 169.254.40.221.
2021-10-21T19:17:32.605Z ERROR [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:154 Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://******.io:443)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: 169.254.40.221 requires the default distribution of Elasticsearch. Please update to the default distribution of Elasticsearch for full access to all free features, or switch to the OSS distribution of 169.254.40.221.
```

Is there anything that I am missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This EOF error is because it is expecting some inputs but it is not receiving. Because you are directly calling the function beat lambda function but the function need to be invoked automatically thats why we are giving triggers. Probably the issue is because AWS is not able to make a successful connection with your elastic cloud. Usually protocol issue (if u are making output.elasticsearch: host as localhost:9200 because AWS doesn't able to reach to this localhost url unless it is a public one) or permission issue. If you check the functionbeat lambda function cloudwatch logs you can able to see the actual issue. Put logging.level: debug in functionbeat.yml for detailed logs.

Also, you cannot see the logs in kibana right after deploying the functionbeat. Once the subscription filter has added to the log group after the successful deployment you have to invoke the function which you have added subscription filter not the functionbeat lambda function. Because the trigger is added to the functionbeat lambda function. So whenever a new item get added into this log group then it will automatically invoke functionbeat lambda function.

Comment: I have updated the error, it shows unable to connect to the elastic search and is complaining about keeping the latest version of Elasticsearch
```2021-10-21T19:17:32.605Z    ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://******.io:443)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: 169.254.40.221 requires the default distribution of Elasticsearch. Please update to the default distribution of Elasticsearch for full access to all free features, or switch to the OSS distribution of 169.254.40.221.```